# How to find the amount of each review based on the average and total number of reviews

Tags: javascript, html, algorithm

So I have this problem that I need to work out for work, but I can't figure out a good algorithm. I am given the average for the reviews and the number of total reviews. From those two pieces of information, I need to randomly generate how many 5 star, 4 star, 3 star, 2 star, and 1 star reviews were made. Here are two formulas that might better explain what exactly the problem is.

```
Given Review Average (x)
Given Total Number of Reviews (y)

Find:
a = # of 5 star reviews
b = # of 4 star reviews
c = # of 3 star reviews
d = # of 2 star reviews
e = # of 1 star reviews

a + b + c + d + e = total # of reviews (KNOWN: y)
(5*a + 4*b + 3*c + 2*d + 1*e) = total number of stars = average(x) * total reviews(y)
```

This is more of a type of math problem than programming, but I need to be able to write some type of algorithm to get a,b,c,d, and e programatically in JavaScript. Does anyone know of any good algorithms for something like this? Thanks!

Comment: See my answer below but I may be misunderstanding.  Are you trying to find all the permutations of `a`, `b`, `c`, `d`, `e` that can give you the answer?

Comment: Not all permutations, just one. Keep in mind that there might be upwards of a million reviews, but obviously the review average will be from 1-5. The algorithm would have to be robust enough to handle large number of reviews.

Comment: "just one"?  Which one?  Any one?  Or are you assuming that the correct one can be found?

Comment: Any one. Any permutation where my two criteria are met (bottom two formulas), is an acceptable answer.

Comment: Why on Earth do you need to generate this much fake review data?  Are you trying to post realistic fake reviews to some unsuspecting website or something?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the maximum possible points total by making everything a 5-star review. You can reduce this total by one by making one of the 5-star reviews a 4-star review. You could continue reducing this by one until everything is a 4-star review. Again, reduce by one by making a 4-star review a 3-star review...

So there is a way to get every possible points total from all 5-stars to all 1-stars, and you can get some sort of answer for every possible total.

Of course, you don't need to compute this point by point. You can start your search by comparing the points total with all 5-stars, all 4-stars.. all 1-stars and find the smallest total bigger than your target. Then change just enough of whatever star you have settled on to the next smallest value to reach your exact target.

(Of course this will look a bit artificial but you couldn't be creating fake review numbers to push products on a sight because this would be false advertising and sooner or later you would get caught).